# LVM on encrypted partition drops me to initramfs root missing

Tags: lvm, cryptsetup

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 64bit on my PC. I have single hard disk (/dev/sda) with LVM encrypted partition.

So the problem is that after reboot I cannot start Ubuntu (it dropped me to initramfs prompt with message: `/dev/mapper/kubuntu....-root missing`)

So I think it is because during boot it cannot open /dev/sda5 with cryptsetup.
If I do chrooting I can open partition and mount encrypted root partition.
I tried to add in grub parameter:

```
cryptopts=target=sda5_crypt,source=/dev/sda5,lvm=vg-root
```

But in cosole during boot I see that No LVM volume is found on sda5?
I also find message:

```
scripts/local_top/cryptroot:line 1 /sbin/cryptsetup: not found
```

Can anybody have idea what is wrong?

I tried system upgrade, created cryptroot file, regenerated initram file.

Comment: I'm also affected by this problem, did you find any solution to it?

Answer (score 10):

The cryptsetup modules are only added to the initramfs image "when there is a device that needs to be unlocked at initramfs stage (such as root or resume devices)" (See: [`conf-hook`](https://salsa.debian.org/cryptsetup-team/cryptsetup/-/blob/f4619d9863fbcd20e16148cff1acc4464cb90d54/debian/initramfs/conf-hook)). But this currently only works (reliably) if the root device is not in an (encrypted) LVM.

To force the cryptsetup modules to the initramfs image you have to set `CRYPTSETUP=y` in `/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook`.

You can also remove the `cryptopts` grub/kernel parameter when adding the `initramfs` option in `/etc/crypttab`:

`sda5_crypt  /dev/sda5  none  luks,initramfs`

I just answered a similar question at [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206754/144250), you might want to have a look there too.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Excellent first answer! +1 already!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem yesterday. I was using BTRFS and Ubuntu had automatically created root and home subvolumes on the filesystem that I wasn't aware of. I needed to edit my `/etc/fstab` to mount these volumes properly.

A tip: once you're in the initramfs shell, play around a bit and see if `ls /root` brings back anything. That led me to my answer.

Comment: Sounds like a different issue.  The OP refers to cryptsetup issues.